# C# - Limpar todos os campos do formulário de uma única vez

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um formulário com vários TextBox, Combobox, RadioButton. E gostaria de limpar todos os campos de uma única vez.
Já vi vários  fóruns, mas não achei o que possa ser meu erro.
Quando vou compilar ele não me retorna nenhum erro e roda normalmente e quando eu clico para limpar os campos  que eu preenchi não acontece nada.
Eu criei o método na classe e no evento Click do Button eu chamei ele.

Na tentei colocar o metodo no mesmo lugar onde está o evento Click e instanciando assim: `ClearForm(this.Control);` Mas não acontece nada também.

Código na classe:

```
    public class Interface
    {
        public void ClearForm(System.Windows.Forms.Control parent)
        {

            foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control ctrControl in parent.Controls)
            {
                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(ctrControl.GetType(), typeof(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)))
                {
                    ((System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)ctrControl).Text = string.Empty;
                }

                else if (object.ReferenceEquals(ctrControl.GetType(), typeof(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)))
                {
                    ((System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)ctrControl).SelectedIndex = -1;
                }

                else if (object.ReferenceEquals(ctrControl.GetType(), typeof(System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton)))
                {
                    ((System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton)ctrControl).Checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No evento Click do Button:

```
        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Interface inter = new Interface();
            inter.ClearForm(this);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse é o método que eu utilizo, já é recursivo e vai limpar todos os controles da tela:

```
public static void ClearControl(Control ctrl)
{
    foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)c).Text = "";
        }
        else if (c is RichTextBox)
        {
            ((RichTextBox)c).Text = "";
        }
        else if (c is ComboBox)
        {
            ((ComboBox)c).SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        else if (c is CheckBox)
        {
            ((CheckBox)c).Checked = false;
        }
        else if (c is RadioButton)
        {
            ((RadioButton)c).Checked = false;
        }
        else if (c is DateTimePicker)
        {
            ((DateTimePicker)c).MinDate = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
            ((DateTimePicker)c).MaxDate = new DateTime(2100, 1, 1);
            ((DateTimePicker)c).Value = DateTime.Now.Date < ((DateTimePicker)c).MinDate ? ((DateTimePicker)c).MinDate : DateTime.Now.Date > ((DateTimePicker)c).MaxDate ? ((DateTimePicker)c).MaxDate : DateTime.Now.Date;
            if (((DateTimePicker)c).ShowCheckBox)
                ((DateTimePicker)c).Checked = false;
        }
        else if (c is NumericUpDown)
        {
            ((NumericUpDown)c).Value = 0 < ((NumericUpDown)c).Minimum ? ((NumericUpDown)c).Minimum : 0 > ((NumericUpDown)c).Maximum ? ((NumericUpDown)c).Maximum : 0;// ((NumericUpDown)c).Minimum;
        }
        else if (c is PictureBox)
        {
            ((PictureBox)c).Image = null;
        }
        else if (c is MaskedTextBox)
        {
            ((MaskedTextBox)c).Text = "";
        }
        else if (c is Label)
        {
            //((Label)c).Text = "";
        }
        else if (c is DataGridView)
        {
            ((DataGridView)c).DataSource = null;
        }
        else if (c is TrackBar)
            ((TrackBar)c).Value = ((TrackBar)c).Minimum;
        else if (c is RichTextBoxExtended)
            ((RichTextBoxExtended)c).ResetText();
        else if (c.HasChildren)
        {
            if (c is TabControl)
                ((TabControl)c).SelectedIndex = 0;

            ClearControl(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Para chamá-lo, de dentro de um Form, basta fazer:

```
ClearControl(this);
```

alterei algumas coisas que utilizo, que são específicas para meu ambiente, mas você pode alterar como preferir.

Comment: Deixei apenas os códigos do Textbox, Combobox e RadioButton. 
E não apareceu nenhum erro, porém quando eu clico para apagar ele aparece uma mensagem (coloquei o Try Catch)  **Desculpe ocorreu um erro: Input string was not in a correct format.** E eu clico em Ok e ele apaga alguns itens, mas a mensagem permanece e toda vez que eu clico em Ok, vai apagando alguns itens. 
Sabe me dizer porque isso está acontecendo?

Comment: olá cristina, só vendo a exceção mesmo, e em qual linha está acontecendo

Comment: Oi!!
Consegui achar meu erro, muito obrigada pela disposição e atenção!